# .forEach() not printing anything in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Have this `.ejs` file that loops through an object and fetches some data from an API. After the data is fetched it just does nothing.

I console logged the API results and they are alright, but the problem is that it is not echoing them to the screen.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="bg-white jumbotron no-shadow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <%
                    if(apiResults.featured.male){
                        %>
                            <div class="row">
                                <%
                                Array.from(apiResults.featured.male).forEach((profile) => {
                                helper.api.getPhotoByKey(profile.photoKey)
                                    .then(photoURL => {
                                        %>
                                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                <img src="<%= photoURL%>">
                                            </div>
                                        <%
                                    })
                                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
                                })%>
                            </div>
                        <%
                    }
                %>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am very new to EJS and NodeJS, can anybody guide me through this? Thank You

Comment: This is the wrong approach; first you grab the results in your express route handler using `Promise.all()`, then you pass them to the template.

Answer (score 1):

Your asynchronous calls won't complete until after the template has already been rendered. You need to get that data together *before* you render the template, e.g.:

```
Promise.all(
    Array.from(apiResults.featured.male)
    .map((profile) => helper.api.getPhotoByKey(profile.photoKey))
    )
    .then(photoURLs => {
        // Add them to your data and call ejs.render...
    });
```

...or similar.

Comment: Does `Promise.all()` make sure that all the promises have successfully resolved?

Comment: @NadirAbbas - Yes. It returns a promise that either rejects if any of the input promises rejects, or resolves with an array of result if all of the input promises resolve. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all